# c# convert words paragraph into list (regex )

Tags: c#, regex, list

I'm building a madlib. I've been Researching regex as a way to do this, but any advice could help. This code example Only functions for the first sentence. Maybe there's a simpler way to do this without regex. Maybe something that can just catch the words in the sentence and ignore the spaces, or use the spaces and punctuations to eventually parse words as objects.

```
class Program
{
string userWord1;
string userWord2;

static void Main()
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    List<string> words2 = new List<string>();
    string userWord1;


    string[] a = SplitWords("Today I went to the zoo."
        + " I saw a " + adjective1 + noun1 + "jumping up and down in it's tree."
        + " He " + verb1 + adverb1 + " through the large tunnel that led to led to it's " + adjective2 + noun2
        + " I got some peanuts and passed them through the cage to a gigantic gray " + noun3 + " towering above my head."
        + " Feeding that animal made me hungry."
        + " I went to get a " + adjective3 + " of ice-cream.
        + " It filled my stomach."
        + " Afterwards I had to " + verb2 + adverb2 + " to catch our bus"
        + " When I got home I " + verb3 + " my mom for a" + adjective3 + " day at the zoo.");

    string[] b = SplitWords2("I saw a adjective noun jumping up and down in it's tree.");





    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.Write(s);
        words.Add(s);
    }

    string sentence = string.Join(",", words.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(sentence);
    Regex r = new Regex(@"\went\b");  //@"\adjective\b")
    sentence = r.Replace(sentence, "@@");
    Console.WriteLine(sentence);


    foreach (string t in b)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
        Console.Write(s);
        words2.Add(t);
    }

    string sentence2 = string.Join(",", words2.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(sentence2);
    Regex br = new Regex(@"\adjective\b");  //@"\adjective\b")
    sentence2 = br.Replace(sentence2, "@@");
    Console.WriteLine(sentence2);

}


static string[] SplitWords(string s)
{

    return Regex.Split(s, @"\Ww+[.?:;!_]");
     @      special verbatim string syntax
     \W + one or more non - word characters together
}


}
```

Comment: Does `String.Split` not work for this problem?

Comment: Is your end goal to have a list/array that contains 1 element for each word found in the paragraph?

Comment: @Wheels73  I should reword it more clearly.  The end goal - (is to eventually)  have a program where I can read in a text through streamreader, and use regex to just replace certain symbols/ words (adjective1, noun2, etc... ). A user will be able type their words in the place of the symbols/words.          The end goal for this example is to do that with the   `string [] a = SplitWords (" string story here").

Comment: are the stories fixed? you could prob get away with using String Interpolation.

Comment: You are misusing an escape in regexes. `@"\adjective\b"` must be `@"\badjective\b"` is you plan to match a word `adjective` inside chars other than letters/digits/`_`.

Comment: @Zach M.  What do you mean by fixed?

Comment: OK. Well if that's the case and if each token you need to replace in the string is unique, i.e. adjective1 or noun1... then I'd just incorporate the string replace method I wouldn't bother with RegEx. Possibly store the tokens and what they're to be replaced with in a Dictionary of <string,string>. You can read the story text into a string via a streamreader then iterate through each token stored and call replace on the story string for each token.